# How to create a reusable component for ant design table columns filter that we can use it for all our table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, components, antd

I want to add filter, search to ant design tables. Based on the documentation, we need to add some props to table column but it will be repeatative. Is there a way that we can creat a seperate component for the columns and filtering those columns?

I tried to develop that component but the column props' do not accept JSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it in this way:

SearchHighliter:

```js
const HighlighterWrapper = memo(({ searchWords, textToHighlight }) => (
  <Highlighter
    highlightStyle={{
      backgroundColor: '#ffc069',
      padding: 0,
    }}
    searchWords={searchWords}
    autoEscape
    textToHighlight={textToHighlight}
  />
))
```

FilterHook:

```js
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Input, Space } from 'antd'
import { SearchOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'

const useTableFilter = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('')
  const [searchedColumn, setSearchedColumn] = useState('')
  const searchInput = useRef(null)

  const handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
    confirm()
    setSearchText(selectedKeys[0])
    setSearchedColumn(dataIndex)
  }

  const handleReset = (clearFilters, confirm) => {
    clearFilters()
    setSearchText('')
    confirm()
  }

  const getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex) => ({
    filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
      <div
        style={{
          padding: 8,
        }}
      >
        <Input
          ref={searchInput}
          placeholder="Search text"
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
          onPressEnter={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
          style={{
            marginBottom: 8,
            display: 'block',
          }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{
              width: 90,
            }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => clearFilters && handleReset(clearFilters, confirm)}
            size="small"
            style={{
              width: 90,
            }}
          >
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: (filtered) => (
      <SearchOutlined
        style={{
          color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined,
          marginRight: 10,
        }}
      />
    ),
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => searchInput.current?.select(), 100)
      }
    },
  })

  return [searchText, searchedColumn, getColumnSearchProps]
}

export default useTableFilter
```

Table:

```js
const SummaryReport = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [searchText, searchedColumn, getColumnSearchProps] = useTableFilter()

  const columns = [
    {
      title: () => <span style={{ paddingLeft: 8 }}>Name</span>,
      key: 'name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      className: 'no-padding-cell-report',
      width: 250,
      ...getColumnSearchProps('name'),
      onFilter: (value, record) => get(record, 'name').toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
      render: (_, record) => (
        <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
          {searchedColumn === 'name' ? (
            <HighlighterWrapper
              searchWords={[searchText]}
              textToHighlight={get(record, 'name') ? get(record, 'name').toString() : ''}
            />
          ) : (
            get(record, 'name')
          )}
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ]

....

}
```

All you need is just provide 2 functions to your column:

- `onFilter` - here you describe your filter logic, if your data object is simple like in my case, the function also is trivial
- `render` - you need to provide this function if you want to highlight text that the user inputs to filter input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the point is that I do not want to repeat that getColumnSearchProps function in every table component that I have. I imagine we have got 15 pages and all of them have their own table, should I copy and paste that function into all of them? I want to know if there is a way to have a filter and search component separately and just add that to any column props that I want

Comment: no, you just need to add `...getColumnSearchProps('name'),` to column

Comment: getColumnSearchProps is reusable, as I said you can create a hook which returns this function

Comment: Would you help me with the hook as well?

Comment: @AbolfazlJamshidi check my updated answer with hook